Can we construct regular icosahedron dice with constant full-face sum?
Recall that regular icosahedron is a convex polyhedron with 20 faces.
And full-face sum is the sum of the numbers on a face itself and its three adjacent faces.
Can we construct regular icosahedron dice using 1~20 exactly once for each face so that full-face sum is always constant?
(But we don't need to make the sum of the numbers on opposite faces constant, like a real dice.)

No, it's not possible.
It is possible to show that each full-face sum must be 42.
Then, you obtain a system of 20 linear equations in 20 unknowns.  Each face yields one linear equation, namely, that the sum of the numbers on four faces is equal to 42, where the unknowns are the numbers on the faces.
If you solve this system of linear equations, you discover that it has only a single solution (it is full-rank), namely, the solution where every face is assigned the number $10.5$.  Of course, this solution violates the requirement that the faces be labelled with integers.
Since the system of linear equations has only one solution, that means there is no solution that meets all of your constraints.
I also wrote a program to search for such a solution using a SAT solver (Z3, specifically), and it reported that there is no solution.  Assuming I did not have any bugs in my code, that is another verification that no such labelling is possible.
